# SoapUI Groovy API documentation

Tags: documentation, groovy, soapui

I'm using `Groovy` scripts as part of our `SoapUI` automation efforts.

I tried looking in SoapUI's website for documentation on their object model and how `Groovy` can be used properly within the `testRunner` context, but I was unable to find anything helpful yet. Since the `Groovy` editor `SoapUI` supplies does not have auto-completion, it is hard to guess which properties each object has.

Is there any good documentation about the APIs and how to use them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please note there are TWO sets of APIs:

1. Pro Version: http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/pro/index.html
2. Free Version: http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html

And the groovy docs: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/

Comment: Thanks, I missed the **Pro** documentation - I actually need those. Also, thanks for the `Groovy` JDK - that was very helpful as well.

Comment: You're most welcome - it took me 2 months to realize there were different docs.

Comment: And the User Guide, for those of us new to Groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/User+Guide

Answer (score 3):

Found it eventually - I was too set on finding `groovy` documentation instead of looking at the `Java API` documentation.

The entry point to the model is a `testRunner` which is actually a `WsdlTestCaseRunner` object.
Its documentation can be found here: 
http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/testcase/WsdlTestCaseRunner.html

From that page I can navigate to the rest of the model if I want.

Answer (score 0):

SmartBear released *Ready API* which is further enhancement to *SoapUI Pro* (both are paid tools) which has context sense help while doing groovy scripting.

And the following [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92WEfVJPJDQ) might be helpful to scripting.

Also would like to add a point that in groovy script test step, the following instance variables are available as you would see the same on the groovy script panel, top of the editor.

1. context
2. log
3. testRunner

And the small tip is that if you type log.info  in the script, you can see some interesting stuff in the log.

For example you can try

```
log.info testRunner
```