# Can any one tell me the difference in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am learning Groovy to use it in Soap UI.

I want to know the basic difference between `[]` and `()` and where it would be used.

`[]` - I understand it is an array..

Typical eg.,

***`()` usage:***

```
def r = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Session").getTestStepByName("InvalidLoginAttempt").run(testRunner, context);
```

***`[]` usage:***

```
def r = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["Login"].getTestStepByName("InvalidLoginAttempt").run(testRunner, context);
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Groovy programming!

When `[]` is used beside an object it invokes the underlying `getAt()` method of an object.

The parenthesis are used to *call a method*, so it *can be* used to invoke a `getAt` method. It varies from implementation.

You can think of it as a syntactic sugar so you don't have to call the whole method. For example, on arraylists:

```
def list = [10, 20, 30, 40]

assert list[2] == 30
assert list.getAt(3) == 40
assert list.get(0) == 10
```

They all work, but the `[]` notation is shorter.

My bet is that SoapUI::TestCases `getAt` probably invokes `getTestCaseByName`, so they are alias to the same operation.

Also worth noting: the `[]`, when assigned to a variable, creates an ArrayList. When used with a equal sign (`list[0] = 90`) it invokes the `setAt()` method of an object/collection.

Comment: where [] is used and where () would be used?

Comment: You'd use `[]` in objects and collections for a shorter syntax; You can also use `()` for invoking the method, but that'd be a little longer. `[]` are usually more idiomatic in Groovy.

Comment: You have to be sure the underlying lib supports both. You can usually check the soapui groovy documentation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106336/soapui-groovy-api-documentation)